# explore function using the stack

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

```
procedure explore(G,v)
Input: G=(V,E) is a graph; v ∈ V
Output: visited(u) is set to true for all nodes u reachable from v

visited(v) = true;
previsit(v)
for each edge (v,u) ∈  E:
    if not visited(u): explore(u)
postvisit(v)
```

Rewrite the explore procedure (above) so that it is non-recursive (that is, explicitly use a stack). The calls to previsit and postvisit should be positioned so that they have the same effect as in the recursive procedure.

solution:

```
procedure explore(G; u)
S = (empty stack)
push(S, u)
while S is not empty:
  v = top(S)
  if not visited[v]:
    visited[v] = true
    previsit(v)
  if there is an edge (v; w) ∈ E with visited[w] = false:
    push(S, w)
  else: (we're done with v, the node at the top of the stack)
    pop(S)
    postvisit(v)
```

Can someone please help me understand this pseudocode, I'm am unsure how Stack works in this case. can someone please walk me through this code so I understand how it works

Comment: Do you know how a stack works abstractly (meaning "in general", outside the scope of this code)? Did you try writing out an example with a small tree (say, with 5 nodes in it)?

Comment: yes i know the general basics of how stack works (LIFO, top, push, pop), its the actual algorithm that uses the stack that's confusing me

Comment: Your best bet at understanding it is to write out an example on paper. It will only take you 5 minutes, trust me. Draw out a simple tree with five nodes, have one section for the stack `S`, have another section for `visited`, and then watch what happens when you execute the algorithm by hand.